# Can S3 Select search multiple objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I'm testing out [S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) and as far as I understand from the examples, you can treat a single object (CSV or JSON) as a data store.

I wanted to have a single JSON document per S3 object and search the entire bucket as a 'database'. I'm saving each 'file' as `<ID>.json` and each file has JSON documents with the same schema.

Is it possible to search multiple objects in a single call? i.e. Find all JSON documents `where customerId = 123` ?

Comment: We have added a script which can loop through the folder and run the S3 Select on files and write it to a file: https://link.medium.com/6vKrErw9qR

Answer (score 30):

It [appears](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html) that Amazon S3 Select operates on only one object.

You can use [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) to run queries across paths, which will include all files within that path. It also supports partitioning.

Answer (score -6):

Simple, just iterate over the folder key in which you have all the files and grab the key and use the same to leverage S3 Select.

Comment: This is not what is asked.