# does aws s3 select work with multiple files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3-select

I'm using S3 select to query a object from a file in S3 bucket but wondering if I can do it with multiple files or if its limited to just one.  I wrote one query from a file using aws lambda but when I tried writing another one for a different file it gave me a error message.

Comment: I am having similar issue. I am capturing incoming messages from a temperatures sensor through AWS IoT in to an s3 bucket. Each s3 object is a new temperature reading. Some thing like ```aws s3api select-object-content --bucket temperatures --key '$aws/things/sensor/shadow/update/accepted/2018-07-13/1531514034796' --expression 'S
ELECT s.desired.temperature from S3Object s ' --expression-type SQL --input-serialization '{"JSON":{"Type": "document"}}'  --output-serialization '{"CSV":{}}'  test --profile myprofile``` works since I specify the one specific key.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721377/can-s3-select-search-multiple-objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can S3 Select search multiple objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721377/can-s3-select-search-multiple-objects)

Answer (score 7):

Amazon S3 Select operates [on only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html) one object.

To query multiple files at once on S3 with a SQL syntax you should use [Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html).